# Connecting native C++ dll with C# by C++/CLI wrapper, Visual Studio issue

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm working on a three projects.

The first one is a native C++ dll, let's name it as a native.dll.

The second is a C++/CLI dll (man.dll), which  contains a bunch of wrapper functions (native.dll is statically linked).

Finally, the man.dll is used( as a reference) in a C# WinForm project. Everything work perfect, I can use a native function in C#, but after a couple(!) builds (in debug mode) the C# project, I can't recompile native.dll, I can't even delete this file because Windows says that the file is being in use by Visual Studio. 
Why?

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Use Process Explorer to see who has a handle to that DLL, sometimes a debug process holds on to it (I saw this occasionally with 2005). Does quitting VS or restarting computer help?

Comment: Disable your virus scanner, especially if it is Avast.

Answer (score 0):

Virus scanner can definately cause problems but in my experience they tend to be intermittent.
Have you tried the obvious things:
- restart visual studio?
- logout then back in?
- reboot?

Silly as it sounds in this day and age - sometimes it really can be that simple...